# 03 ford expedition with a poor idle to start

Tags: ford, rough-idle, expedition

Please can you tell me what else do I have to check to solve the problem.......because what I have done in my truck haven't helped. It does start the engine but after I try two or three times after that seems to work fine. Thank you

Comment: What have you done with the truck so far?

Comment: Is there a Check Engine Light on? If so, have you read the codes?

Comment: If it runs fine when **not** idling, I would check the *idle air control*.

Answer (score 1):

Thoroughly Clean the throttle body with approved aerosol cleaner then reset idle strategy.

To reset idle strategy disconnect battery for 5 minutes, reconnect battery and start engine with all accessories off, do to touch steering wheel or brakes pedal, let idle on its own for 15 minutes, then turn ac on high and let idle for another 15 minutes, turn off.

Idle strategy is re learned now.